# design of button

Tags: html, button

How remake design of this like button:

[image]

On this: (photoshop)

[image]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each( $('.voting_wrapper'), function(){
        var unique_id = $(this).attr("id");
        post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'fetch'};
        $.post('vote_process.php', post_data,  function(response) {
                $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(response.vote_up); 
                $('#'+unique_id+' .down_votes').text(response.vote_down);
            },'json');
    });
    $(".voting_wrapper .voting_btn").click(function (e) {
        var clicked_button = $(this).children().attr('class');
        var unique_id   = $(this).parent().attr("id");      
        if(clicked_button==='down_button') //user disliked the content
        {           
            post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'down'};

            $.post('vote_process.php', post_data, function(data) {

                //replace vote down count text with new values
                $('#'+unique_id+' .down_votes').text(data);

                //thank user for the dislike
                alert("Thanks! Each Vote Counts, Even Dislikes!");

            }).fail(function(err) { 

            //alert user about the HTTP server error
            alert(err.statusText); 
            });
        }
        else if(clicked_button==='up_button') //user liked the content
        {
            //prepare post content
            post_data = {'unique_id':unique_id, 'vote':'up'};

            //send our data to "vote_process.php" using jQuery $.post()
            $.post('vote_process.php', post_data, function(data) {

                //replace vote up count text with new values
                $('#'+unique_id+' .up_votes').text(data);

                //thank user for liking the content
                alert("Thanks! For Liking This Content.");
            }).fail(function(err) { 

            //alert user about the HTTP server error
            alert(err.statusText); 
            });
        }

    });
    //end 



});


</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.content_wrapper{width:500px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;}
h3{color: #979797;border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD;font-family: "Trebuchet MS";}

/*voting style */
.voting_wrapper {display:inline-block;margin-left: 20px;}
.voting_wrapper .down_button {background: url(images/thumbs.png) no-repeat;float: left;height: 14px;width: 16px;cursor:pointer;margin-top: 3px;}
.voting_wrapper .down_button:hover {background: url(images/thumbs.png) no-repeat 0px -16px;}
.voting_wrapper .up_button {background: url(images/thumbs.png) no-repeat -16px 0px;float: left;height: 14px;width: 16px;cursor:pointer;}
.voting_wrapper .up_button:hover{background: url(images/thumbs.png) no-repeat -16px -16px;;}
.voting_btn{float:left;margin-right:5px;}
.voting_btn span{font-size: 11px;float: left;margin-left: 3px;}

-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="content_wrapper">
        <!-- voting markup -->
        <div class="voting_wrapper" id="1001">
            <div class="voting_btn">
                <div class="up_button">&nbsp;</div><span class="up_votes">0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="voting_btn">
                <div class="down_button">&nbsp;</div><span class="down_votes">0</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- voting markup end -->



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I thank for every answerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want it to look like this? https://jsfiddle.net/byB9d/6221/

I used `font-awesome` icons instead like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="content_wrapper">
        <!-- voting markup -->
        <div class="voting_wrapper" id="1001">
            <div class="voting_btn">
                <span class="up_votes">0</span><br>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="voting_btn">
                <span class="down_votes">0</span><br>
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- voting markup end -->



</div>
```

.
    **CSS**

```
.content_wrapper{width:500px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;}
h3{color: #979797;border-bottom: 1px dotted #DDD;font-family: "Trebuchet MS";}
.voting_btn span{font-size: 11px; }
.voting_btn{float: left; margin: 10px; text-align: center;}
```

Comment: Have you used font-awesome before?